# WSO2 EMM - Response Signing Failed

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-iot

I'm trying to change the default `localhost` certificates for Enterprise Mobility Manager. I've folowed the instructions in https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon441/Creating+New+Keystores. But I still got the error:

> ERROR {SSO Module} -  Response Signing failed

in a java stack, there is also error

```
java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 128
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using WSO2 IS as IDP when configuring SSO?

Comment: Did you solved your problem?